# Two issues with libgdx List widget

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to use the libgdx List widget to make a list of all the items in an arraylist.  Well, actually my arraylist is a list of objects, and each of the objects contains a string that is the objects "name".

However, when I try to show these with a List, it lists them horizontally, not vertically.  If I try to show the contents of a normal array it lists the contents vertically.  I am implementing Screen in my classes.

For example,

```
ArrayList<String> PartyListEntries = new ArrayList<>(); 

private List PartyList = new List(skin);

PartyListEntries.add("ham");
PartyListEntries.add("hag");
PartyListEntries.add("ham");
PartyList.setItems(PartyListEntries);

table.setFillParent(true);

table.top().left().padTop(10).padLeft(10);
table.add(PartyList);

stage.addActor(table);
```

This shows: [ham, hag, ham]

But if I make a String array and have the array contents be { "ham", "hag", "ham" }

then it shows

[ham]

[hag]

[ham]

horizontally(without the line breaks).

This is my first issue with list.  My 2nd issue is that when string values are the same, it selects both of them.  In the 2nd example, if I set the default selection to index zero it will put both index 0 [ham] and index 2 [ham] as selected.  It will do this for every string that has the same value as whatever is selected.  I.. don't want it to do this.  I want them to be treated as unique since they are.

I am trying to look at the code for List but to be honest it's kind of beyond me.  I don't know what causes these problems.  I could really try to figure it out and I might and it will take me a long time, but I figure maybe you guys already know what is causing this.  Or maybe can just offer me a good alternative to List.

Thanks!

Comment: I solved the horizontal vs vertical issue by passing the String values within my arraylist into a normal array with a for loop.  I don't know why I have to do that, but whatever, it works.  I still will need to figure out how to solve the second issue though.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the first question: the Libgdx widget just uses the `toString` method of whatever object you give it to make the text label. So that's why you get different results with lists and String arrays. It was just the preference of whomever wrote each of those classes how to format the array to a String. If you want to use the List class, you could subclass it and change the `toString` method to the way you want it, or you could create a List wrapper class that does its own method of converting the list to a String.

Regarding the second question: This is a peculiarity of Java. If you hard code strings (put them in your actual code in a class with quotation marks), then the compiler makes all matching strings into a single shared instance of the String class. So "ham" and "ham" are the same instance of String, the same object.

You can get around this by wrapping your string with a String constructor like this. `new String("ham")`. This will force it to create a separate instance of String.

Example:

```
String s0 = "a";
String s1 = "a";
String s2 = new String("a");
boolean b0 = s0.equals(s1); //evaluates true
boolean b1 = s0.equals(s2); //evaluates true
boolean b2 = s0==s1; //evaluates true
boolean b3 = s0==s2; //evaluates false
```

If you load your strings in from a file at runtime, matching strings will be different instances.